# Vuetify datatable select all with disabled checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, datatable, vuetify.js, disable, selectall

I'm having an issue with datatables with select rows. I have rows which have the checkbox disabled, but the select all checks them anyway...
Is this a bug?

I made a codepen: https://codepen.io/slayerbleast/pen/jOWjzWJ

How can I fix the selectAll checkbox only check the available checkboxes?

Template:

```
<v-content>
    <v-data-table
        v-model="selected"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        item-key="name"
        show-select
    >
    <template #item="{ item }">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <v-checkbox
                    :disabled="item.calories > 250"
                    class="pa-0 ma-0"
                    :ripple="false"
                    v-model="selected"
                    :value="item"
                    hide-details
                >
                </v-checkbox>
            </td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.calories}}</td>
            <td>{{item.fat}}</td>
            <td>{{item.carbs}}</td>
            <td>{{item.protein}}</td>
            <td>{{item.iron}}</td>
        </tr>
    </template>
    </v-data-table>
</v-content>
```

data:

```
data: () => ({
        selected: [],
            headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name',
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
          { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
          { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
          { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
        ],
        desserts: [...]
})
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On a `v-data-table` component you can set a `selectable-key` property:

> The property on each item that is used to determine if it is selectable or not

If not specified, it uses `isSelectable` by default. What you can do is to create a computed property to add this info to your `desserts` attribute like so:

```js
computed: {
  enrichedDesserts() {
    return this.desserts.map(x => ({ ...x, isSelectable: x.calories <= 250 }));
  }
}
```

Then change the `items` property of your `v-data-table`:

```html
<v-data-table :items="enrichedDesserts">
```

Please see this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/chamboug/pen/zYrgqwy) for a working example.